# Using Microsoft Graph API how do I get DriveItem's Audio fascet?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am able to query the Microsoft Graph API successfully for DriveItems but I am struggling to get it to return the fields I want:

My code is as follows:

```
        LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();
        requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("select", "name,id,audio"));

        return MicrosoftGraphHelper.getClient()
                .me()
                .drive()
                .root()
                .search(DriveItemSearchParameterSet.newBuilder().withQ(".mp3").build())
                .buildRequest(requestOptions)
                .getAsync()
```

This is equivalent to the following Graph API call:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.mp3')?select=name,id,audio](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q=%27.mp3%27)?select=name,id,audio)

The result I get contains the "name" and "id" field but it does NOT contain the audio field.  It is null even though I know the audio fields are populated on the driveitems.

How do I tell the API to expand the audio field and retrieve, for example, "title" and "artist"?

I've looked at all the Microsoft Graph API documentation but nothing is jumping out as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I finally fixed this...

The code above is indeed correct.  The problem was that I was logging into my work OneDrive account rather than my personal OneDrive account.

The audio facet (and probably the photo and video facets) is only available for personal accounts.